# didSelectRowAtIndexPath Problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Hi i am having a problem with didSelectRowAtIndexPath where my app crashes with EXC-BAD-ACCESS when a row is selected. The strange this is that i have the exact same piece of code in the accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath and it correctly displays the detail view. Here is the code for this method.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

    if(childController == nil)
    {
        childController = [[ScoreCardDetailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ScoreCardDetailView" bundle:nil];
    }

    ScoreCard *selectedScoreCard = [self.list objectAtIndex:row];

    if([self checkPlusMinus:selectedScoreCard.score]==0||[self checkPlusMinus:selectedScoreCard.score]==1)
    {
        childController.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@  +%d",selectedScoreCard.course.courseName, selectedScoreCard.score];

        childController.selectedScoreCard = selectedScoreCard;
        UIBarButtonItem *newBackButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle: @"Back" style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target: nil action: nil];

        [[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem: newBackButton];

        [newBackButton release];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:childController animated:YES];

    }
    else
    {
        childController.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@  %d",selectedScoreCard.course.courseName, selectedScoreCard.score];

        UIBarButtonItem *newBackButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle: @"Back" style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target: nil action: nil];

        [[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem: newBackButton];

        [newBackButton release];
        childController.selectedScoreCard = selectedScoreCard;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:childController animated:YES];
    }

    childController=nil;

}
```

Comment: Can please tell us on which line of the posted source the app crashes. And please also post the stack trace. Otherwise it's just guessing.

Comment: The posted code looks okay except for a likely memory leak, which however is not the cause of the crash. The memory leak is the _childController_ instance. You create it in this method and at the end of the method set the variable to _nil_. You should release it first. Why is _childController_ an instance variable anyway (and not a local variable)? Since you always set it to _nil_, it is probably not used anywhere else.

Comment: The code completes its after the last line it fails. There is no stack trace in the console when the error occurs.

Comment: The documentation says of the viewController you push onto the stack: "This object cannot be an instance of tab bar controller and it must not already be on the navigation stack." If the object is on the stack it throws an exception. Seems unlikely, but might be worth checking to see if childController is nil when you enter this method, i.e. whether a new ScoreCardDetailViewController gets created or not.

Comment: childController is always nil when this method is entered it seems a bit stupid to even have that check. I have added break points and the viewdidload and the viewdidappear code seems completes ok its when it hits the final brace in method the error occurs. I am beginning to pull my hair out. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Please post the stack trace. It doesn't appear in the console, but in the debugger window. And I don't understand: "The code completes its after the last line it fails."

Answer (score 0):

try replacing "childController=nil;" with "[childController release];"

Answer (score 0):

Ok i have fixed it but can not understand why it works. I released the child controller in the dealloc method and set it to nil in the viewdidunload and the problem was fixed. Can anyone shed any light on why this fixed the problem?

Comment: Your vc was released but not set to nil so at some point during execution the check [vc == nil] returned false when it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

I implore anyone who has random crashes in their app they can't explain to add NSZombieEnabled into the build environment, there are guides to do this available online and it will save you loads of time!